# Dynamic categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Perhaps a stupid question, but how do I create a category, that shows products with a particular attribute, dynamically? Meaning, when I add more products, they would show up there?

Thanks!

Comment: My extension will do exactly what you require: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-dynamic-category-products.html

Answer (score 2):

You can give [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products) a try.
It does not really work with categories but it allows you to build product lists based on rules.
The rules are created in a similar way you create the catalog discount rules.
The pages that list products based on rules support url rewrites, descriptions, images just like categories to and you can add them to the top menu.
more details about how it works [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki)

Comment: do you have it for Magento 2?

Comment: Not yet. Maybe someday.

Comment: OK, if only someday would be soon, I would be sooo happy :), Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a good question, but the answer involves a little bit of work. There is  more than one way of doing this, but one method is as the following.

Create an observer that listens to the event that fires after a category is saved. It will be something along the line of `catalog_category_save_after`.

This observer then kicks off a process that will load a collection of products with the attribute value of your liking. Let's call this attribute `categorical_data`.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('categorical_data', $yourValueHere);
```

Assign the products from the collection into this category. Refer to [Adding products to a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491548/programatically-add-magento-products-to-categories) for more details.

How you create or load the category depends on how you want to do it.